# How to extract data from the JSON file with multiple values

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON data file and i am able to parse data from it.
However when i am trying to parse the topic section as below i am getting multiple entries seperated by comma. Can someone help me with this? I am new to Python.

```
import json
data = json.loads(data)

for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
    print(item['Topics'])
```

Output:

```
{'Topic1': {'Code': '201', 'Value': 'Products'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '207', 'Value': 'Mergers / Acquisitions'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '210', 'Value': 'Officer Changes'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '252', 'Value': 'Other Pre-Announcement'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '245', 'Value': 'Earnings Announcements'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '245', 'Value': 'Earnings Announcements'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '252', 'Value': 'Other Pre-Announcement'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '253', 'Value': 'Strategic Combinations'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '213', 'Value': 'Divestitures / Spin-offs'}, 'Topic2': {'Code': '264', 'Value': 'Product Responsibility'}}
{'Topic1': {'Code': '265', 'Value': 'Community'}}
```

When i am running the below script it gives me:

```
for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
    print(item['Topics']['Topic1']['Value'])
```

Output:

```
Products
Mergers / Acquisitions
Officer Changes
Other Pre-Announcement
Earnings Announcements
Earnings Announcements
Other Pre-Announcement
Strategic Combinations
Divestitures / Spin-offs
Community
```

Instead i want the result to be like this.

```
Products
Mergers / Acquisitions
Officer Changes
Other Pre-Announcement
Earnings Announcements
Earnings Announcements
Other Pre-Announcement
Strategic Combinations
Divestitures / Spin-offs,Product Responsibility
Community
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: kindly share the original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate again `item['Topics']` to get nested level dictionary values, To get similar result from your input.

You can try something like this:

```
for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
    for topic, topic_value in item['Topics'].items():
        print(topic_value['Value'])
```

#### Edited based on comment

```
for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
    res = ''
    for topic, topic_value in item['Topics'].items():
        res = res + ', ' + topic_value['Value']
    res = res[2:]  # To remove unwanted ', ' at index 0,1
    print(res)
```

Comment: Hi @shivam This works good. But is there a way i can print this like Topic1,Topic2. Your solution is listing topics one by one.

Answer (score 1):

So in your example,  topic1 and topic2 are both keys in a dictionary. If you want both values, you can just do ...

```
for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
    for entry in item['Topics'].keys():
        print(item[entry]['Value'])
```

The idea behind this code to nest a second loop and use the `keys()` methods to get a list of the keys in the dictionary at that level of the structure, that way if there were top3, topic4, etc. it would also find them.

Comment: hi @matt I am getting an error when i run your code: it says  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-263-c714515ce9b3> in <module>
      4 for item in data['GetSignificantDevelopments_Response_1']['FindResponse']['Development']:
      5     for entry in item['Topics'].keys():
----> 6         print(item[entry]['Value'])

KeyError: 'Topic1'

Comment: Can you share the original data? According to what I see, the code I shared can't error that way, but the data as a whole may be different.